# Qgis instalation by OSGEO

Tags: qgis, installation, osgeo4w

I've tried install Qgis 3.0 (and 2.18) using OSGEO. I'm using windows 10.

I've followed the steps I found in youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G1WyUGYHC0I and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4NCtprMYyg4).

Summing up, OSGEO acomplish download, but the installation process always stops at 93% (sometimes 94%). In the window is showing:

```
Running
          qgis
          /etc/postinstall/qgis.bat
```

In Task Mannanger, for OSgeo4w-setup-x86 is indicated:

```
    1- Console Window Host
    2- NirCmd
    3- osgeo4w-setup-x86
    4- Windows comad processer (sorry for pour translate!)
```

I finished last task (4), and then this mensage was noticed:

```
Postinstall script errors These do not necessarily mean that affected packageswill fail to function properly but please check /var/log/setup.lo.full and report problems 
    Package: gdal-python
             gdal-python
```

The installation was completed, Qgis is starded, but I can not open my projects.

Can someone help me solve this problem and install qgis?
I think this problem is related to .bat. Will be?

Comment: Strange, do you check the log file as the error suggest?

Comment: I don't know how and where this log is saved. I'm begginer in this way and I usually am only a user. Yesterday I tryied install qgis by begginer way and I couldn't acomplish. The instalation process stop close to finish. Can you help me, please?

Comment: First delete the folders of previous installation (generally **C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18**). Then download and run the QGIS 2.18 standalone installer [HERE](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html)

Comment: I deleted all previous folders and windows registers. After that, I tried install by Osgeo again and it worked. I don't know why, but Qgis is working now. Thanks for your attention, Oscar!

Comment: Well done!! If you find usefull someone of my comments please upvote them ;)